# macro defined using loops

Tags: c, macros

I have to pass a macro `mode_n` to a macro `set_field` in a library. `mode_n` is defined using `mode_one`

```
#define mode_one(k, phi) cos(k*x + phi)
```

`x` is defined in `set_field`. `phi` is a random number. `mode_n` is the sum of a series of `mode_one` which have different `k` and `phi`. One simple example of `mode_n` is

```
#define mode_n (mode_one(1, 0.5) + mode_one(2, 0.4) + mode_one(3, 0.9))
```

There are 3 terms. It will be tedious if there are hundreds of terms like this. That's why I hope to define `mode_n` using a loop.
I expect `n` to be one argument of `mode_n`. `set_field` is macro like this

```
#define set_field(mode_n) { \
double x, f; \
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { \
    x = i * 10; \
    f = mode_n; \
}
```

Is it possible to define `mode_n` using C macros?

Comment: Can you show something that looks like a code of what you are talking about? It is very unclear now.

Comment: Macros are a pure compile-time feature, they are replaced by the preprocessor with the macro expansion. Once the code has passed the preprocessor there are no traces left of the macros that the compiler "proper" sees.

Comment: So you're trying to pass a macro into `set_field` so that `set_field` can call your macro with `x`? This is not possible, macros are expanded before compilation so you can't pass a reference to a macro like you can a function.

Comment: Don't write macros like that, be very careful with them, write `cos((k)*(x) + (phi))` instead, google why.

Comment: What do you mean with: "*has to be one macro with unknown `x`*", if you mean that `x` is a variable you can pass `x` as a macro parameter too. If `x` is always `x`, then simply use the `mode_one` style. But I think that is terribly bad, because it makes the definition of the macro have no sense. An also you can always use functions.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Questions is updated

Comment: @iharob set_field is still a macro in the library. It requires mode_n to be a macro. I have no choice to pass mode_n as function. And mode_n can have hundreds of terms. If we don't use a loop, mode_n will be very long.

Comment: @Trey set_field is still a macro

Comment: @JoachimPileborg set_field is a still macro

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can put a loop in a macro. Put it in one line or multiple lines. If it is multiple lines, you need to put an escape character at the end of the line.